# How to retrieve float_val from a PredictResponse object?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow

I am running a prediction on a tensorflow-serving model, and I get back this `PredictResponse` object as output:

**Result:**

```
outputs {
  key: "outputs"
  value {
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    tensor_shape {
      dim {
        size: 1
      }
      dim {
        size: 20
      }
    }
    float_val: 0.000343723397236
    float_val: 0.999655127525
    float_val: 3.96821117632e-11
    float_val: 1.20521548297e-09
    float_val: 2.09611101809e-08
    float_val: 1.46216549979e-09
    float_val: 3.87274603497e-08
    float_val: 1.83520256769e-08
    float_val: 1.47733780764e-08
    float_val: 8.00914179422e-08
    float_val: 2.29388191997e-07
    float_val: 6.27798826258e-08
    float_val: 1.08802950649e-07
    float_val: 4.39628813353e-08
    float_val: 7.87182985462e-10
    float_val: 1.31638898893e-07
    float_val: 1.42612295306e-08
    float_val: 3.0768305237e-07
    float_val: 1.12661648899e-08
    float_val: 1.68554503688e-08
  }
}
```

I would like to get the out the float vals as a list. Or, alternatively, return the value/index of the argmax float_val!

This is generated by:

> stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel)
>   result = stub.Predict(request, 200.0)

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 10):

The answer is:

```
floats = result.outputs['outputs'].float_val
```

Comment: Same problem but `result.outputs['outputs'].float_val` returns type `<type 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedScalarContainer'>`. How did you convert this into list of floats?

Comment: The answer for TF 1.2+ is: `result.result().outputs['outputs'].float_val`

Comment: Convert it to list and then numpy array if you'd like, floats = numpy.array(list(result.outputs['outputs'].float_val))

Answer (score 10):

You generally want to recover a tensor, with a shape (not just a long list of floats). Here's how:

```py
outputs_tensor_proto = result.outputs["outputs"]
shape = tf.TensorShape(outputs_tensor_proto.tensor_shape)
outputs = tf.constant(outputs_tensor_proto.float_val, shape=shape)
```

If you prefer to get a NumPy array, then just replace the last line:

```py
outputs = np.array(outputs_tensor_proto.float_val).reshape(shape.as_list())
```

If you don't want to depend on the TensorFlow library at all, for some reason:

```py
outputs_tensor_proto = result.outputs["outputs"]
shape = [dim.size for dim in outputs_tensor_proto.tensor_shape.dim]
outputs = np.array(outputs_tensor_proto.float_val).reshape(shape)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it addresses the general-case scenario.

Comment: I had to do .reshape((shape)) to get this to work. But I agree with jamix on this one. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Note, that the result may not be in ["outputs"]. In my case it was in ["score"]. But this was the right answer for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to convert the entire PredictResponse to a numpy array (including its dimentions)

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/eavidan/22ad044f909e5739ceca9ff9e6feaa43.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please help me how to get the predictions along with probabilities, I am getting the same output from TF-serving that is only probabilities.?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for tensorflow-serving-api-python3 1.8.0

`result.outputs['your key name'].float_val #key name in your case is outputs`

This will return a repeated scalar container object. Which can be passed to python list() or np.array() etc

Answer (score 0):

`result["outputs"].float_val` should be a python list

Comment: Hi Alexandre, Thank you for your response. But I got: Traceback (most recent call last):
`line 95, in main
    vals = result['outputs'].float_val
TypeError: 'PredictResponse' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: results.value[0].float_val then

Comment: Does not work: AttributeError: 'PredictResponse' object has no attribute 'value'