# How to get float_val from a PredictResponse object?

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, tensorflow-serving

I'm having exactly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44785847/how-to-retrieve-float-val-from-a-predictresponse-object) problem:

After running a prediction on a tensorflow-serving model, I'm getting back this PredictResponse object as output:

```
outputs {
  key: "scores"
  value {
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    tensor_shape {
      dim {
        size: 1
      }
      dim {
        size: 2
      }
    }
    float_val: 0.407728463411
    float_val: 0.592271506786
  }    
}
```

As suggested in that question, I tried using:
    result.outputs['outputs'].float_val

but then it returns type `<type google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedScalarContainer>`

It is being produced by this piece of code, inspired in inception_client.py example:

```
channel = implementations.insecure_channel(host, int(port))
stub = prediction_service_pb2.beta_create_PredictionService_stub(channel)
result = stub.Predict(request, 10.0)  # 10 secs timeout
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`result.outputs['scores'].float_val[0]` and `result.outputs['scores'].float_val[1]` are the float values in this response.

For future reference, the [documentation for the python bindings to protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated) explains this and other issues.

Comment: Thanks! I edited it because I had to use `result.outputs['scores'].float_val[0]` instead of `result.outputs['outputs'].float_val[0]` as suggested, I tink it's because of the field 'keys' saying 'scores'.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have more than one outputs with their names stored in the `output_names` list, you can do something like the following in order to create a dictionary with output names as keys and a list with whatever the model returns as values.

```
results = dict()
for output in output_names:
    results[output] = response.outputs[output].float_val
```