# Unable to take Input values from Tensorflow Serving client request

Tags: arguments, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to deploy my tensorflow model in a tensorflow serving using tensorflow saved model. Input for my tf model is a string value and i have defined my signature as below

```
        prediction_signature = (
            tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
                inputs={'input_path': tensor_info_input},
                outputs={'output_prediction': tensor_info_output},
                method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME))

        builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
            sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
            signature_def_map={
                'predict_images':
                    prediction_signature,
            })
```

My objective is to read a image from the path specified in signature definition. How do i get the input_path from input definition and convert the tensor into actual string value to read the path

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add some "reading operation" in your model file.

Like this:

```
def inference(image_path_string):
    # read image from a image path string
    image_file = tf.read_file(image_path_string)
    image_raw = tf.cond(tf.image.is_jpeg(image_file),
                        lambda: tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file, channels= 3 if rgb, else 1),
                        lambda: tf.image.decode_bmp(image_file))
    # image preprocessing code
    ...
    ...
    # your prediction model code
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: I agreed, but my question is how to get the values from 'input_path' defined in signature and pass the value to function you mentioned def inference(image_path_string):  .

Answer (score 0):

You can place the below mentioned code in a Python file say, Client.py. And for inference, you can run the below mentioned command in the Terminal

```
python Client.py --image abc/0.png --model mnist --signature_name predict
```

This will take the path of the image, "abc/0.png" and will convert it to Numeric Values, and will run the inference.

Code for Client.py is mentioned below. The below code is for MNIST Images. You can reshape your images accordingly:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import time
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread

import grpc
from tensorflow.contrib.util import make_tensor_proto

from tensorflow_serving.apis import predict_pb2
from tensorflow_serving.apis import prediction_service_pb2_grpc


def run(host, port, image, model, signature_name):

    channel = grpc.insecure_channel('{host}:{port}'.format(host=host, port=port))
    stub = prediction_service_pb2_grpc.PredictionServiceStub(channel)

    # Read an image
    data = imread(image)
    data = data.astype(np.float32)
    print(data)

    start = time.time()

    # Call classification model to make prediction on the image
    request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
    request.model_spec.name = model
    request.model_spec.signature_name = signature_name
    request.inputs['image'].CopyFrom(make_tensor_proto(data, shape=[1, 28, 28, 1]))

    result = stub.Predict(request, 10.0)

    end = time.time()
    time_diff = end - start

    # Reference:
    # How to access nested values
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44785847/how-to-retrieve-float-val-from-a-predictresponse-object
    print(result)
    print('time elapased: {}'.format(time_diff))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--host', help='Tensorflow server host name', default='localhost', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--port', help='Tensorflow server port number', default=8500, type=int)
    parser.add_argument('--image', help='input image', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--model', help='model name', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--signature_name', help='Signature name of saved TF model',
                        default='serving_default', type=str)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    run(args.host, args.port, args.image, args.model, args.signature_name)
```

For more information, you can refer this beautiful article on Tensorflow Serving,
https://medium.com/@yuu.ishikawa/serving-pre-modeled-and-custom-tensorflow-estimator-with-tensorflow-serving-12833b4be421